# ios - load pdf depending on device orientation and jumping to a page

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf

Here is the situation - my client has a pdf document, in two versions, portrait and landscape layout. He wanted me to write an application which would load the pdf based on device orientation, and when the orientation changes, the other corresponding version would get displayed.

Here is the use case

- start device in landscape mode - landscape.pdf is loaded
- device changes orientation to portrait - portrait.pdf is loaded and shown
- device changes orientation to landscape - landscape.pdf is shown

This is all easy to do, but the real culprit is the fact that pdf files have more than one page, and when device changes orientation while displaying some other page than first, it would need to jump directly to that page.

My question is whether this is possible in iOS? Can I load a PDF and jump directly to a specific page?

Comment: It would help to know what technology / object / code you use to display the PDF files...

Comment: I am loading the pdfs into UIWebView, so nothing fancy, is this of any help? Here is the method which does it - http://pastie.org/5630823

Answer (score 0):

if you use UIWebView to load the PDF, and there is a scrollview, you can specific the location.